# Which version of the application will Google Play provide to users as an update?

Tags: android, google-play, version, google-play-console, semantic-versioning

A mental situation:

0. There is a v1.0.0 version of the app in Play Market
1. I'm releasing version v1.0.1 of the app (in Play Market, the update is apparently for everyone)
2. Some users are not able to update (let's say the user has disabled auto-updates or simply does not have access to the internet)
3. I am releasing the following version of the application v1.0.2 (or v1.1.0, or v2.0.0)

**Question:** what version will users who skipped the update in step 2 get? Does it depend on whether a major, minor, or patch version was released?

I think there is some connection between the major versions, but I haven't found any information on that.

Any information and any source would be helpful. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, really: users receive the highest versionCode they're eligible to receive based on which testing tracks they've joined (if any) and which device they have (which must match the app restrictions, e.g. feature availability, minSdkVersion, etc.).

Note that the versionCode is used, not the versionName (so there's effectively no major or minor version here).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! It turns out that all migrations relying on `versionCode` will have to be dragged through all subsequent versions of the application...(